# Solve for $v(t)$ if $\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{49^2-v^2}{245}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve for $v(t)$ if $\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{49^2-v^2}{245}, v(0) = 0$.

I know how to find the family of solutions for something like $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = ay-b$, but the squared part makes it more complicated for me, and I can't use the same process. My book says the answer is $v = 49\tanh(t/5)$ m/s.

Comment: This question was in the early pages of my differential equations book, so I don't think advanced methods will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly looking at the answer, I think the problem should have contained $49^2 + v^2$. However, with the minus sign, it is

$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{49^2-v^2}{245}$

$\dfrac{dv}{(7 +v)(7 - v)} = \dfrac{dt}{245}$

$\dfrac{dv}{7 - v} - \dfrac{dv}{7 + v} = \dfrac{2dt}{35}$

$\log(\dfrac{7-v}{7 + v}) = \dfrac{2t}{35} + c$

Now c can be found using initial condition, $c = 0$

Comment: As I've remarked earlier, basic integration knowledge is needed in order to solve differential equations. We shall wait to see other answers and learn more.

Comment: Sorry you are right this seems to be the way to do it.

Comment: $v^2-9$ is the correct version. If it were $v^2+9$, the final solution is the same but with $\tan$ instead of $\tanh$.